# Two header files and two .CPP files

Tags: c++, function, structure, header-files

These files are shortened down from a bigger program.

I am having trouble compiling these files in c++ and I am not completely sure what the problem is. I have changed the parameters of the function to include the variables course_holder and course_count but that adds more errors.

what am i doing wrong?

---

struct_header.cpp

```
#ifndef FILENAME_H
#define FILENAME_H
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

struct course_struct        
{
string course_ID;
};

#endif
```

func_proto.h

```
//func_proto.h
#ifndef FUNCTIONS_H
#define FUNCTIONS_H

void add_course(course_struct (& array_course)[10][100]);

#endif
```

functions.cpp

```
// functions.cpp
#include "struct_header.h"
#include "func_proto.h"

void add_course(course_struct (& array_course)[10][100])
{ // start f1
    cout << "ENTER COURSE ID> ";
    cin >> course_holder;

    array_course[course_count][0].course_ID = course_holder;  // course ID = user input
    cout << course_holder;

    course_count++; // increment for the next time this function is run 
    return;
}// end f1
```

main_funct.cpp

```
#include "struct_header.h"
#include "func_proto.h"

course_struct array_course[10][100];

int course_count = 0;  
string course_holder; 

int main()
{
     add_course(array_course);

     return 0;
}
```

and the errors

```
functions.cpp: In function ‘void add_course(course_struct (&)[10][100])’:
functions.cpp:8:9: error: ‘course_holder’ was not declared in this scope
functions.cpp:10:15: error: ‘course_count’ was not declared in this scope
func_proto.h:5:33: error: variable or field ‘add_course’ declared void
func_proto.h:5:50: error: ‘array_course’ was not declared in this scope
func_proto.h:5:62: error: ‘course_struct’ was not declared in this scope
```

Comment: You're using `course_holder` all over the place when it isn't defined until right before `main`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need declaration for `course_count` and `course_holder` in `functions.cpp`

```
extern int course_count;  
extern string course_holder;
```

Comment: That does help, thank you. Is there anything to do with the last three errors? the ones that aren't reading the structure.

Comment: Same problem. You're not declaring things (in the proper places).